# close popup by clicking outside of it in foreach functions

Tags: javascript

i've created a sample project with a card slider, inside this slider i've created a foreach functions that open a popup when the card is clicked, with some information.

the problem is that i can't find a way to close popup if i click outside of the popup elements.

here a reproducible example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7hg4y9ro/

my function:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.cards')

cards.forEach((card => {

    const getName = card.querySelector('.footer-left')
    const getPrice = card.querySelector('.footer-right')

    function showPopup() {
        const el = document.getElementById('cards-container');
        const popup = document.createElement('div')
        popup.setAttribute('class', 'card-popup')

        popup.innerHTML = '' +
            '<div class="close-card-popup" id="close-card-popup">&times;</div>' +
            '<p class="card-popup-text">Il prezzo di ' + getName.innerText + ' è di:</p>' +
            '<p class="card-popup-price">' + getPrice.innerText + ' €' +
            '<div class="card-popup-center"><button class="card-popup-button">Acquista il prodotto</button></div>'

        const overlay = document.createElement('div')
        overlay.setAttribute('class', 'overlay')
        el.appendChild(overlay)
        el.appendChild(popup)

    }

    card.addEventListener('click', showPopup)

}))
```

Comment: One way is to add an event listener on the document body and in your event handler, detect if the popup is open, and if so close it.

Comment: could you make an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add at the end of your showPopup() function this code:

```
    function closePopup(){
        popup.remove()
        overlay.remove()
    }
    overlay.addEventListener('click', closePopup)
    var elem = document.querySelector('.close-card-popup')
    elem.addEventListener('click', closePopup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating elements, you could delete them. Like this:

```
function hidePopup() {
    document.querySelector('.card-popup').remove()
    document.querySelector('.overlay').remove()
}

function showPopup() {
    const el = document.getElementById('cards-container');
    const popup = document.createElement('div')
    popup.setAttribute('class', 'card-popup')

    popup.innerHTML = '' +
        '<div class="close-card-popup" id="close-card-popup">&times;</div>' +
        '<p class="card-popup-text">Il prezzo di ' + getName.innerText + ' è di:</p>' +
        '<p class="card-popup-price">' + getPrice.innerText + ' €' +
        '<div class="card-popup-center"><button class="card-popup-button">Acquista il prodotto</button></div>'

    const overlay = document.createElement('div')
    overlay.setAttribute('class', 'overlay')
    el.appendChild(overlay)
    el.appendChild(popup)
    
    document.querySelector('.close-card-popup').addEventListener('click', hidePopup)
    document.querySelector('.overlay').addEventListener('click', hidePopup)
}
```

But I'd do it with CSS instead of JS using the :target pseudo class.

Comment: this doesn't work, because the element does not exist in the dom initially